# Python EAFP Loop Exercise

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm taking the Udacity Python course, and while I know how to code in the 'traditional' sense, I've been trying to code like a Python Developer by practicing EAFP (*Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission*) methods when possible. The following is the prompt provided:

```
# Define a procedure, union, that takes as inputs two lists.
# It should modify the first input list to be the set union of the two
# lists. You may assume the first list is a set, that is, it contains no 
# repeated elements.


def union(list1, list2):
try:
    [list1.append(x) for x in list2 if list1.index(x) < 0] 
except:
    print 'Nope'    


# To test, uncomment all lines 
# below except those beginning with >>>.

a = [1,2,3]
b = [2,4,6]
union(a,b)
print a 
#>>> [1,2,3,4,6]
print b
#>>> [2,4,6]
```

Instead, the result I receive is a "Nope" and printing a will return [1,2,3] (definitely not doing combining the lists).

I didn't do any returns because lists can mutate.

I was wondering where my error is with the code I listed? And is EAFP even worth implementing everywhere?

Comment: you dont know about set???

Comment: Before calling your union function, try `a.index(8)`. Hopefully you'll see where to go from there.

Comment: @Marius I see! Yes, error handling problem there. But how would I append be able to append the items that aren't in the list using EAFP (try/except)?

Comment: Well, a better check to see if the item is already in the list would be `if x not in list1`. As far as the bigger picture of EAFP goes, you should always try to check only for *specific* exceptions rather than catching all of them, so figure out which exceptions will be raised and do `except ExampleException:`.

Comment: Excellent advice @Marius! Thank you for the insight into EAFP. Also, based on the suggestion you provided for a.index(8), I solved the problem via try/except!

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems here:

The first problem has to do with the way Python exceptions work.  If I do the following:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [2,4,6]

[a.append(x) for x in b if a.index(x) < 0]
```

I'll get a `ValueError` as 4 isn't in the list.  The union will never complete because the first miss will cause the code to error out.

If you're against using `set()`, then I suggest using a search that won't cause an error, the `count()` method:

```
[a.append(x) for x in b if a.count(x) > 0]
```

The second problem I see is the idea of using EAFP as a general design principle.  I direct your attention to [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which states:

> ...know when to be inconsistent -- sometimes the
>   style guide just doesn't apply. When in doubt, use your best judgment.
>   Look at other examples and decide what looks best. And don't hesitate
>   to ask!

Although PEP 8 deals with code style, the spirit of these words are good guidance when it comes to approaching solving a problem with Python-- stick with the rules, within reason.

EAFP is one of those loose rules.  If you're working with a system that is stable, the API is well-formed and explicit, and the number of exceptions that could arise with is manageable, then EAFP works pretty well.  The code is clean, and it's fast.

However, there are instances when that doesn't always work.  For example, if you are using data from outside sources as a feed into your production system, you will never be 100% certain that the data can't be mangled, corrupted, or malformed.  It's up to you as the designer to determine what level of LBYL paranoia needs to be in place before EAFP can reasonably work.

Answer (score 0):

using set : set can do this for you

```
>>> def union(a,b):
...     return list(set(a)|set(b))
... 
>>> union([1,2,3,4],[2,3,7,8])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8]
```

read about set here:[set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set)

Comment: This is a nice function/method, but not what I asked. I was hoping to utilize try/except methods to practice basics before diving into new methods. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

I found a great solution thanks to @Marius pointer

```
def union(list1,list2):
    for x in list2:
        try:
            list1.index(x)
        except ValueError:
            list1.append(x)
```

I realized the problem was that with index, I didn't utilize the except the way I should. For example, when the a.index(x) returns an Error, I merely returned Nope. Where in fact, the reason why the error is even launched is because the variable x does not exist in list a, which raises the error.

Comment: This is not the best way to use Try/Except, this can be done using if 'for x n list2: if x not in list1: list1.append(x)'. You should distinguish between ways to use Try/Except, and if/else.

Comment: @user3378649 Apparently this question is from an exercise that specifically encourages you to use EAFP. I can't see any obvious places to put a `try`/`except` in this function, but this solution seems like a pretty good way to meet the requirements of the exercise.